# When I write to two files in python, the second one is always empty

Tags: python, file-io

I'm working on a simple python script to write some data to two text files. My code looks like this:

```
with open('file1.txt', 'w') as file1:
    for thing in stuff1:
        file1.write(thing + '\n')

with open('file2.txt', 'w') as file2:
    for thing in stuff2:
        file2.write(thing + '\n')
```

When I run the program, file1 turns out as expected, but file2 is empty.

However, if I switch the order in which I write to the files (meaning I write to file2 first and then to file1), file2 turns out as expected and file1 is empty.

In other words, the file to which I write second always turns out empty.

I tried adding file1.flush() / file2.flush() inside of the loops, but to no avail. Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: what are `stuff1` and `stuff2`? Your writing to file seems ok assuming they have content.

Comment: Did you have changed `stuff1` and `stuff2`?

Comment: The Redundancy Department of Redundancy wants to know why you're writing the code out twice. Make it a function that takes a `stuff` and a `filename`.

Comment: For this to be a complete, reproducible problem you need to provide more code or explanation than you have above. Based on what you have provided, any answers will only be guesses. Specifically, we need to know what is inside (or supposed to be inside) of `stuff1` and `stuff2`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Alternatively, it could also be a procedure that takes a `filename` and a `stuff`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but your problem is likely that `stuff1` and `stuff2` are pointing to the same generator or iterator, and you can only iterate through once. After that, its contents are exhausted.

Try this instead:

```
import itertools

stuff1, stuff2 = itertools.tee(the_source_generator_or_iterator_or_whatever)

with open('file1.txt', 'w') as file1:
    for thing in stuff1:
        file1.write(thing + '\n')

with open('file2.txt', 'w') as file2:
    for thing in stuff2:
        file2.write(thing + '\n')
```

Comment: That worked! I didn't realize that the iterator could be 'exhausted' and I wouldn't be able to run through it again.

Comment: yup, that's how they work. iterators aren't like lists, sets, dictionaries, or other containers. they don't take up memory by "holding" all the members. there's literally no way the iterator *could* go through its members again. it's in the very nature of the thing to forget, and that's part of the reason they are useful (light on memory, fast, etc).

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you had the line

```
stuff2 = stuff1
```

before your code snippets and stuff1, stuff2 are generators. If so they would be aliases for the same generator. The first write loop exhausts the (single) generator.

Comment: This is essentially Rick's answer -- but just with a guess as to the source of the alias

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `stuff2` is empty.
You can print the variable to debug before going into the second for-loop.